# How do I get command-line options of a program in GNU Info?

Tags: gnu

The program I'm using doesn't have a man page and I need more detail on all the command-line options it has. It has a GNU Info page but I'm sure how to quickly get at the command-line options without searching through the index. Is there a command-line option for GNU Info that lets me do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can type in the following to get the command-line options of a program:

```
info --show-options program
info --usage program
info -O program
```

Here's a list of command-line options for invoking GNU Info: http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/html_node/Invoking-Info.html